# Is this an NP problem?

Tags: np-complete, subset-sum

first off I'm going to say I don't know a whole lot about theory and such. But I was wondering if this was an NP or NP-complete problem. It specifically sounds like a special case of the subset sum problem.

Anyway, there's this game I've been playing recently called Alchemy which prompted this thought. Basically you start off with 4 basic elements and combine them to make other elements.

So, for instance, this is a short "recipe" if you will for making elements

```
fire=basic element
water=basic element
air=basic element
earth=basic element
sand=earth+earth
glass=sand+fire
energy=fire+air
lightbulb=energy+glass
```

So let's say a computer could create only the 4 basic elements, but it could create multiple sets of the elements. So you write a program to make any element by combining other elements. How would this program process the list the create a lightbulb?

It's clearly fire+air=energy, earth+earth=sand, sand+fire=glass, energy+glass=lightbulb.

But I can't think of any way to write a program to process a list and figure that out without doing a brute force type method and going over every element and checking its recipe.

Is this an NP problem? Or am I just not able to figure this out?

Comment: May not be helpful, but this looks like a job for Prolog.

Comment: it's in P, and therefore also in NP. However, it is not NP-complete.

Comment: You can write a verification for it pretty simply, so it's in NP at least.

Comment: lijie - if P = NP then all problems in P are NP complete, so if you say a problem in P is not NP complete, you are saying P != NP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How would this program process the list the create a lightbulb?

Surely you just run the definitions backwards; e.g.

1. Creating a lightbulb requires 1 energy + 1 glass
2. Creating an energy requires 1 fire + 1 air

and so on.  This is effectively a simple tree walk.

OTOH, if you want the computer to figure out that energy + glass means lightbulb (rather than "blob of molten glass"), you've got no chance of solving the problem.  You probably couldn't get 2 gamers to agree that energy + glass = lightbulb!

Comment: yea, this actually makes sense. for your last comment, in the game it was actually electricity+glass but electricity had a long definition so I shortened it. I think I was seeing the problem in a different way that wasn't reversible like this but didn't phrase it correctly. Anyway this is the correct answer for how I phrased it though

Answer (score 3):

You can easily model your problem as a graph and look for a solution with any complete search algorithm. If you don't have any experience, it might also help to look into [automated planning](http://spiderman-2.laas.fr/planning/). I'm linking to that text because it also features an introduction on complexity and search algorithms.